# Masstransit Message consumer won't reconnect

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

We are using RabbitMQ and MassTransit as our messaging infrastructure in out application.

I have a scenario where my consumer needs to stop processing messages for a while and then restarted at some later point.

I can successfully stop the bus and consumer stops processing further messages but when I restart the bus it says bus already started, but the consumer won't pickup any more messages for further processing

Sample code looks like

```
var iBusControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
    {
        h.Username("guest");
        h.Password("guest");
    });

    if (linkConsumer)
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("TestMessage_Queue", x =>
        {
            x.Consumer<TestMessageConsumer>();
        });
});

iBusControl.Start();
// Consumer starts processing messages

// later on in the code I call stop on the same bus instance
iBusControl.Stop();
// Consumer stops processing messages    

// later on in the code I call start again on the bus instance
iBusControl.Start();
// Masstransit also says, bus already started
// But the consumer won't pick up any further messages for processing.
```

Bus if I create a new instance of the bus same as the first block of my code and call start on it, it will connect the consumer correctly and message processing starts again. Few questions/confusions

1. Is this the expected behaviour?
2. Does stopping the bus removes all receive endpoint configuration?
3. Why can't I start the bus after stopping it?

Using MassTransit 5.3.3 with RabbitMQ 3.6.14 Erlang 20.1

Comment: I believe that the bus cannot be started after it was stopped. The application needs to be restarted. For me, what you are trying to do is a design smell. There must be some other way to address this requirement.

Comment: What we are trying to do is stop picking further messages if we can't process because of a broken dependency further downstream. Example I have given above isn't production design.

Comment: You need to use a circuit breaker, redelivery and other available methods. All those patterns are widely known and properly described.

Comment: Not being rude here, I am not looking for design suggestion. I am familiar with those patterns. My question is around why MassTransit is behaving in certain manner.

Comment: You can't restart a stopped bus instance. You need to reconfigure a new instance and start it. Just expand your restart loop to include reconfiguration and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [release of masstransit v7.1.0](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.0.html), the bus can be restarted after being stopped. Before that, this was not possible.

From the release notes:

> Since MassTransit's inception, it has never been possible to Start a bus that was previously Started and then Stopped. With this release, a bus can now be started, stopped, started, and stopped, and started, and stopped...